# How can I trigger alert event when I click on a toolbar kendo Mobile button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

Im trying to call a function when I click on my custom toolbar button. I want to see if the function is called by implementing the alert() function inside of it. It doesnt trigger any message tho. Any idea how to check if the function is triggered by clicking on a button beside alerting?

CODE:

```
....

toolbar: [
                {template: '<a class="k-button" onclick="removeLicense()">Ukloni licencu</a>'}
         ],
...

 function removeLicense() {
//  window.kendoAlert("hello");
        alert("hello");
    }
```

Comment: do you have a `<script></script>` tag wrap your function?

Comment: why not onclick="alert("hello")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/IpIya) which will trigger your alert when the toolbar button is clicked.

Hope this helps.